# How logic and code codeigniter take the session data of the page view registration process to be used as a temporary session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3, session-variables

How to retrieve data from a session array with only one value for the registration session data only and how the example logic code implementation of the page contains sessions, the user is required to register first, so if the user tries to access by refreshing the page, there is no text output in the form of being required to register first with the following code

```
<?php

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $variabelInpUtusername = $this->input->post("email");
        $variabelInputPass = password_hash($this->input->post("password"), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(
            'email',
            'Email',
            'required|is_unique[tb_register.username]',
            array('is_unique' => 'Ini %s sudah terdaftar', 'required' => 'Anda harus input email')
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required', array('required' => 'Anda harus input password'));
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('register');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $data = array('username' => $variabelInpUtusername, 'password' => $variabelInputPass);
            // print_r($data);
            // $this->modeluser->register($data);
            $datasession['sessi'] = array('username' => $variabelInpUtusername, 'password' => $variabelInputPass);

            $this->session->set_userdata($datasession);
            // print_r($datasession);
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('sukses_register', $datasession);


            // $this->session->set_userdata($datasession);
            // print_r($datasession);
            // var_dump($datasession);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the **set_value** function from helper library. Please check the document for more information. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: @JaydeepChauhan It doesn't work, with the following code

Comment: @JaydeepChauhan `$newdata = array( 'username' => $variabelInpUtusername, 'password' => $variabelInputPass); $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata); $this->load->view('sukses_register');`

I clicked the browser arrow again, and refreshed it again, still able to display the successful registration page